# How to get column mean grouped by row labels in R dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this

| Fruit | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 12 | 29 |
| Bananas | 11 | 31 |
| Apples | 44 | 55 |
| Oranges | 30 | 73 |
| Oranges | 19 | 82 |
| Bananas | 24 | 78 |

The Fruit names are not ordered so I can't group them by taking n at a time, they're listed randomly. I need to get the mean of fruits sold in 2021 & 2022 as well as mean sold for apples, oranges & bananas for each year separately.

My code is

```
2021 <- c(mean(df$2021), sd(df$2021))
2022 <- c(mean(df$2022), sd(df$2022))
measure <- c('mean','standard deviation')

df1 <- data.table(measure,TE,TW,NC,SC,NWC)
```

and output looks like this:

| Measure | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 23.3 | 58 |
| standard deviation | 12.4 | 23.3 |

But I'm not sure where to start with grouping the rows by name. I need to get something that looks like this

| Measure | 2021 | Apples | Bananas | Oranges | 2022 | Apples | Bananas | Oranges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 23.3 |  |  |  | 58 |  |  |  |
| standard deviation | 12.4 |  |  |  | 23.3 |  |  |  |

(with the appropriate numbers in the blank spaces)

Comment: Do you want the mean and sd of apples/Bananas/..etc for each year ?

Comment: Must your data be in that final format? It does not seem ideal. If not, there are plenty of simple options to get the mean and SD by year across all fruits. Also, the column names `2021` and `2022` are problematic - R won't allow names of objects to start with numbers. So something is wrong with these example data.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this might be better (in the long run) in a long format, which this summarizing can get started. This is just 'mean', not hard to repeat for `sd` and combine with this:

```r
fruits <- c(NA, "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas")
lapply(quux[,-1], function(yr) stack(sapply(fruits, function(z) mean(yr[is.na(z) | quux$Fruit %in% z])))) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "year")
#   year   values     ind
# 1 2021 23.33333    <NA>
# 2 2021 28.00000  Apples
# 3 2021 24.50000 Oranges
# 4 2021 17.50000 Bananas
# 5 2022 58.00000    <NA>
# 6 2022 42.00000  Apples
# 7 2022 77.50000 Oranges
# 8 2022 54.50000 Bananas
```

where `NA` in `ind` indicates all fruits, otherwise the individual fruit labeled.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your data in long form, you could use the aggregate function:

```
a <- aggregate(value ~ year + fruit, data=df, FUN=function(x) c(sd(x),mean(x))
```

Where `value` is a column you could create to put the values which are now under `2021` and `2022`. Then create a new column called `year` which has `2021` or `2022` accordingly. Long form is the way to go in R almost always.

Comment: I agree that long format is the way to got, but to be a complete answer your response should provide the mechanism to obtain long format data from their originally posted data, as the other answers have provided

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = 'year') %>% 
   as.data.table %>%
   cube( .(Mean = mean(value), SD = sd(value)),
     by = c("Fruit", "year")) %>% 
   filter(!if_all(Fruit:year, is.na)) %>% 
   unite(Fruit, Fruit, year, sep = "_", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
   filter(str_detect(Fruit, "_|\\d+")) %>% 
   data.table::transpose(make.names = "Fruit", keep.names = "Measure")
```

-output

```
    Measure Apples_2021 Apples_2022 Bananas_2021 Bananas_2022 Oranges_2021 Oranges_2022     2021     2022
1:    Mean    28.00000    42.00000    17.500000     54.50000    24.500000    77.500000 23.33333 58.00000
2:      SD    22.62742    18.38478     9.192388     33.23402     7.778175     6.363961 12.42041 23.57965
```

---

Or if we want the duplicate column names

```
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = 'year') %>% 
   as.data.table %>%
   cube( .(Mean = mean(value), SD = sd(value)), by = c("Fruit", "year")) %>%
    mutate(Fruit = coalesce(Fruit, year)) %>%
   drop_na(year) %>%
   arrange(year, str_detect(Fruit, '\\d{4}', negate = TRUE)) %>% 
   select(-year) %>% 
   data.table::transpose(make.names = "Fruit", keep.names = "Measure")
```

-output

```
   Measure     2021   Apples   Bananas   Oranges     2022   Apples  Bananas   Oranges
1:    Mean 23.33333 28.00000 17.500000 24.500000 58.00000 42.00000 54.50000 77.500000
2:      SD 12.42041 22.62742  9.192388  7.778175 23.57965 18.38478 33.23402  6.363961
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Fruit = c("Apples", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", 
"Oranges", "Bananas"), `2021` = c(12L, 11L, 44L, 30L, 19L, 24L
), `2022` = c(29L, 31L, 55L, 73L, 82L, 78L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```